# Adding customised stopwords on top of the default list

Tags: r, stop-words, quanteda

I am running topic models and I am trying to put the uninterpretable words into my customised stopword lists on top of the default stopword lists to improve the model performance.

```
all_stops <- c("fat","monkey","ce","fallen",stopwords("en"))
dfm_1 <- tokens(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
 tokens_remove(pattern = all_stops)%>%
 dfm() %>%
 dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 15, min_docfreq = 20,max_docfreq = 250)
dfm_stem <- dfm(dfm_1,stem=TRUE)
```

But the words that I have tried to get rid of (e.g. monkey) still appear on my model output.
I would like to ask if my code has anything wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to reproduce your problem without having access to `corp` from your data, but my test below indicates that this works fine.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1.0
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

corp <- "The monkey ate the banana.  Time flies like a banana."

all_stops <- c("fat", "monkey", "ce", "fallen", stopwords("en"))

tokens(corp, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(pattern = all_stops) %>%
  dfm() %>%
  # dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 15, min_docfreq = 20, max_docfreq = 250) %>%
  dfm_wordstem()
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 5 features (0.00% sparse) and 0 docvars.
##        features
## docs    ate banana time fli like
##   text1   1      2    1   1    1
```

Note that I've commented out your `dfm_trim()` since otherwise it would have removed all of the features.  Also note that the `stem` in `dfm(x, stem = )` is deprecated; here I've used `dfm_stem()` instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply Prof Benoit. I am still using version 3.0.0. Is it possible that this might be the reason for not being able to get rid of the customised stopwords? On that note, I would like to confirm if the 'stem' in dfm(x, stem= ) is still functioning albeit with the warning of deprecation in quanteda 3.1.0.